# I'm getting errors when trying to access WordPress beyond installation

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm to connect XAMPP to WordPress. So I can migrate a theme I created over but when i hit the login to WordPress button I'm met by error code.

I'll post below for anyone who understands it.

Thank you for any help!

I've tried a few tutorials on how to do this but I continue to get the same problems. I've also tried to access the user document in question but it wont allow me to.

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'remember' in
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\NRFG_WP\wp-includes\user.php on line 39
>
> Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\NRFG_WP\wp-includes\user.php on line 39
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'user_login' in
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\NRFG_WP\wp-includes\user.php on line 54
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot create references to/from string
>   offsets in C:\xampp1\htdocs\NRFG_WP\wp-includes\user.php:54 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp1\htdocs\NRFG_WP\wp-login.php(770): wp_signon('',
>   '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp1\htdocs\NRFG_WP\wp-includes\user.php
>   on line 54

Here's the PHP up until all lines mentioned:

```
<?php
/**
 * WordPress User API
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Users
 */

/**
 * Authenticate user with remember capability.
 *
 * The credentials is an array that has 'user_login', 'user_password', and
 * 'remember' indices. If the credentials is not given, then the log in form
 * will be assumed and used if set.
 *
 * The various authentication cookies will be set by this function and will be
 * set for a longer period depending on if the 'remember' credential is set to
 * true.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param array $credentials Optional. User info in order to sign on.
 * @param bool $secure_cookie Optional. Whether to use secure cookie.
 * @return WP_User|WP_Error WP_User on success, WP_Error on failure.
 */
function wp_signon( $credentials = array(), $secure_cookie = '' ) {
    if ( empty($credentials) ) {
        if ( ! empty($_POST['log']) )
            $credentials['user_login'] = $_POST['log'];
        if ( ! empty($_POST['pwd']) )
            $credentials['user_password'] = $_POST['pwd'];
        if ( ! empty($_POST['rememberme']) )
            $credentials['remember'] = $_POST['rememberme'];
    }

    if ( !empty($credentials['remember']) )
        $credentials['remember'] = true;
    else
        $credentials['remember'] = false;

    /**
     * Fires before the user is authenticated.
     *
     * The variables passed to the callbacks are passed by reference,
     * and can be modified by callback functions.
     *
     * @since 1.5.1
     *
     * @todo Decide whether to deprecate the wp_authenticate action.
     *
     * @param string $user_login    Username, passed by reference.
     * @param string $user_password User password, passed by reference.
     */
    do_action_ref_array( 'wp_authenticate', array( &$credentials['user_login'], &$credentials['user_password'] ) );
```

Comment: All these warnings/error messages are very googleable, but not answerable without code and variable samples. They mostly indicate a string value, where an array should be.

Comment: @mario I've bee able to access a separate copy of the file. I hope this can help you help me. I started from scratch but still the same problem. Trying to Google these lines hasn't got me a straight answer yet.

Comment: Is this a clean installation? any active themes or plugins

Comment: No its a clean install